# Отправка письма с несколькими вложениями php ajax, приходят битые картинки

Tags: php, email

Имеется форма отправки письма с сайта

```
<form id="form" class="popup-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Заполните форму</h4>
        <input type="text" class="name" name="fname" placeholder="Имя" required="" aria-required="true"/><br>
        <input type="text" class="lastname" name="flastname" placeholder="Фамилия" required="" aria-required="true"/><br>
                    <input type="text" class="phone" name="fphone" placeholder="Телефон" required="" aria-required="true"/><br>
        <input type="email" class="remail" name="femail" placeholder="E-mail" required="" aria-required="true"/><br>
                    <textarea class="msg" id="msg" class="msg" name="fmsg" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" required="" aria-required="true"></textarea>

        <p class="hide"><span><input type="file" name="ufile[]"></span><a class="del_file" href="#">Удалить</a></p>
        <p class="hide"><span><input type="file" name="ufile[]"></span><a class="del_file" href="#">Удалить</a></p>
        <p class="hide"><span><input type="file" name="ufile[]"></span><a class="del_file" href="#">Удалить</a></p>
        <p class="hide"><span><input type="file" name="ufile[]"></span><a class="del_file" href="#">Удалить</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="add_file">Добавить файл</a></p>

        <br>
        <button class="rbutton">Отправить</button>
    </form>
```

посредством jquery Ajax данные передаются в обработчик

```
<?php

$recepient = "myemail@yandex.ru";
$sitename = "mysite.ru";

$username = trim($_POST["fname"]);
$lastname = trim($_POST["flastname"]);
$useremail = trim($_POST["femail"]);
$userphone = trim($_POST["fphone"]);
$usermsg = trim($_POST["fmsg"]);
$message = "$usermsg <br><br><br>Имя: $username $lastname<br>E-mail: $useremail<br>Телефон: $userphone";

$subject = "Сообщение с сайта \"$sitename\" - блок сообщения";

$file = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];

function send_mail($email, $subject, $message, $useremail, $file)
{
    $boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $useremail\r\n";
    $multipart = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";
    $multipart .= "$message\n\n";

    $message_part = "";
    foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
       $fp = fopen($value, "r");
       $file = fread($fp, filesize($value));
       $message_part .= "--$boundary\r\n";
       $message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
       $message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$value\"\n\n";
       $message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file)) . "\r\n";
    }
    $multipart .= $message_part . "--$boundary--\r\n";

    mail($email, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}

send_mail($recepient, $subject, $message, $useremail, $file);
```

Сообщение приходит вместе с файлами, но все файлы битые и весят по 1 байт.

Где ошибка?

Comment: В send_mail передается только название файла, а нужно передать еще $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] - путь к файлу на сервере, чтобы использовать его в fread. Вообще не понимаю как foreach работает, в него же строка передается? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я опирался на один скрипт, который на этом же сайте обсуждался, похожий вопрос, признаюсь сам путаюсь, но письмо отправить получилось, если бы еще и файлы дошли...

Comment: @ZaurK. Используйте [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) или [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer), там attachment идёт из коробки.  У меня к вам большая просьба: не городите свои велосипеды. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с почтой удобно пользоваться готовыми решениями [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) или [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

Пример отправки файлов с помощью Swiftmailer

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Your subject')
    ->setFrom(array('webmaster@mysite.com' => 'Web Master'))
    ->setTo(array('receiver@example.com'))
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

foreach( $_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"] as $tmp_name){
    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($tmp_name));
}

//send the message          
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую с библиотекой Swiftmailer

Answer (score 0):

name должен быть разный,ипользуйте `<input type="file" multiple>`

Comment: Нет, не должен, name используется правильно согласно документации php. Ваш multiple даст точно такой же `$_FILES`, так что по сути это не ответ на вопрос