# Помогите допилить PHP скрипт для отправки текстовых сообщений и картинок на почту

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет нужна помощь в допиливании формы обратной связи с возможностью прикреплять фото. С последующей отправкой на почту естесно. Так как я не в зуб ногой в php прошу помощи у почтенных специалистов. Заранее благодарен.
Вот что есть у меня:

```
<?php

session_start();

// переменная, в которую будем сохранять результат работы
$data['result']='error';

// если данные были отправлены методом POST, то...
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // устанавливаем результат, равный success
    $data['result']='success';
    //получить имя, которое ввёл пользователь
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
      $data['result']='error';
    } 
    //получить email, который ввёл пользователь
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    } else {
      $data['result']='error';
    }
     //получить сообщение, которое ввёл пользователь
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];     
    } else {
      $data['result']='error';
    }

    $uploaddir = './uploads/';
    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $_FILES as $file ){
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']) ) ){
            $files[] = realpath( $uploaddir . $file['name'] );
        } else {
            $data['result']='error';
        }
    }
  } else {
    //данные не были отправлены методом пост
    $data['result']='error';
  }
  // дальнейшие действия (ошибок не обнаружено)
  if ($data['result']=='success') {

    //1. Сохранение формы в файл
    $output = "---------------------------------" . "\n";
    $output .= date("d-m-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
    $output .= "Имя: " . $name . "\n";
    $output .= "Номер телефона: " . $phone . "\n";
    $output .= "email: " . $email . "\n";
    if (file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/message.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX)) {
      $data['result']='success';
    } else {
      $data['result']='error';         
    } 

    //2. Отправляем на почту
    // включить файл PHPMailerAutoload.php
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    //формируем тело письма
    $output = "Дата: " . date("d-m-Y H:i") . "\n";
    $output .= "Имя: " . $name . "\n";
    $output .= "Номер телефона: " . $phone . "\n";
    $output .= "email: " . $email. "\n";
    // создаём экземпляр класса PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
    $mail->From      = 'email@сайт.ru';
    $mail->FromName  = 'Имя сайта';
    $mail->Subject   = 'Запрос на оценку';
    $mail->Body      = $output;
    $mail->AddAddress( 'email@gmail.com' );
        $mail->addAttachment( '../uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'] );

    // отправляем письмо
    if ($mail->Send()) {
      $data['result']='success';
    } else {
      $data['result']='error';
    }      
  }
  // формируем ответ, который отправим клиенту
  echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Вообщем переделал скрипт, подключил **PHPMailerAutoload.php** для упрощения отправки письма. Все работает кроме привязки фото к письму. На сервер фотки загружаются а к письму не хотят приаттачиватся!
Посмотрите что не так. Спасибо.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516047/186083 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562444/186083 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461273/186083

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
    $mail->From      = 'email@сайт.ru';
    $mail->FromName  = 'Имя сайта';
    $mail->Subject   = 'Запрос на оценку';
    $mail->Body      = $output;
    $mail->AddAddress( 'email@gmail.com' );
```

> **$mail->addAttachment( '../uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'] );**

Заменил выделенный жирным кусок на вот этот и все заработало.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        $mail->addAttachment( $uploaddir . $file['name'] );
    }
```